# Why isn't XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.Map producing tooltips?

Tags: f#, google-visualization, fslab

I'm trying to plot locations on a map with XPlot and googlecharts.chart.map.

I followed the example I found, but the resulting map had no tool tips on the specified locations.

To debug my code I simply attempted to reproduce the example, with the same result, i.e. no markers at the specified locations.

My implementation of the example (https://fslab.org/XPlot/chart/google-map-chart.html) is below:

```
let data =
        [
            "China", "China: 1,363,800,000"
            "India", "India: 1,242,620,000"
            "US", "US: 317,842,000"
            "Indonesia", "Indonesia: 247,424,598"
            "Brazil", "Brazil: 201,032,714"
            "Pakistan", "Pakistan: 186,134,000"
            "Nigeria", "Nigeria: 173,615,000"
            "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh: 152,518,015"
            "Russia", "Russia: 146,019,512"
            "Japan", "Japan: 127,120,000"
        ]


let options = XPlot.GoogleCharts.Configuration.Options(showTip = true)

let chart =  data 
             |> XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.Map
             |> XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.WithOptions options
             |> XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.WithHeight 420
             |> XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.WithWidth 800

chart |> XPlot.GoogleCharts.Chart.Show
```

The map is shown without any markers.

How should the code be modified to ensure the locations are marked?

Comment: The [example script](https://fslab.org/XPlot/chart/google-map-chart.html) shows tool tips just fine given FsLab is `correctly initialized` by running `FsLab.fsx`. Last line in your script with `Show(chart)` is not needed.

Comment: In my initial attempt, I did not use FsLab but added a reference to XPlot.GoogleCharts directly. I've tried a new console app using FsLab and still encounter this issue. If I don't include the last line, the map isn't displayed, and if I do include the last line, a map is displayed in the browser, but without tool tips. Is there a way to display the chart that I have missed?

Comment: Well, the chart produced by F# console app generating html that is then shown in a web browser is a setup quite different, than one in `FSLab` where the chart html is put into `suave` server as a page, then being shown by a browser.

Comment: I think I understand now, I think the issue is that the html has to be part of a live website for the map to be updated with tool tips.

Comment: Nope, your guess is wrong. You've forced me to compose an answer (kinda). I'll publish it shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing tooltips problem source is not in your code, but in the ambient environment.

If you use your F# console charting app code without any changes, but bind it with nuget package [XPlot.GoogleCharts ver 1.4.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPlot.GoogleCharts/1.4.2) instead of the latest at the moment [XPlot.GoogleCharts ver 1.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPlot.GoogleCharts/), it will work as expected, i.e. **tooltips will be present** even on the html static page viewed in the browser.

The regression, I believe, has nothing to do with `XPlot.GoogleCharts` per se and is likely caused by the [change to the way of loading JS libraries introduced by Google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#updateloader): `XPlot.GoogleCharts ver 1.4.2` uses the old [loader](https://www.google.com/jsapi) , while the latest `XPlot.GoogleCharts ver 1.5.0` uses the [new one](https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js).